# ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'month' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I somehow get that error in chrome's console even though visual studio code doesnt give me any errors.

Here's my code in my interfaces.ts

```
export interface Data1{
month: string;
employeeName: string;
date: string;
employmentStatus: string[];
```

}

and here's my code in tables.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Data1 } from '../../../shared/interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tables',
  templateUrl: './tables.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tables.component.css']
})
export class TablesComponent implements OnInit {
  today = new Date();
  dataForTable1: Data1;
  months: string[] = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
  ]

  constructor() { 
    console.log(this.today.getMonth());
    console.log(this.months[this.today.getMonth()]);
    this.dataForTable1.month = this.months[this.today.getMonth()]
    this.dataForTable1.employeeName = '';
    this.dataForTable1.date = this.today.getDate().toLocaleString();
    this.dataForTable1.employmentStatus = [''];
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I tried debugging using console.log but it gives me the correct outputs but I don't know why it says undefined.
I'm currently using Angular CLI: 1.7.4; Node: 8.11.1; Typescritp: 2.8.1
Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: The reason you aren’t getting a compile-time error from Typescript is because the error is a runtime error (similar to an object ref error in C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define Data1 as class and not interface or you need to define a concrete class based on that interface. Then instantiate it so you can use its properties.

```
this.dataForTable1 = new SambleClass()
```

Comment: It worked! But in my previous project I used and interface and used it the same way as I use in this project. The only difference was I used the interface as an array like this
`products: IProduct[] = []`
and it worked. Did that worked because products was initialized with = []?